# I need to know which is better ? to use session or auth()->user()->property

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, session

I'm working on a social website and when I login, I need some information about the user to use in the front-end such as name, image link, username, id.

So which is better to use, a session to store all data I need, or just using 
auth()->user()->property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use auth() helpler :

```
auth()->user()
```

Or Auth Facade :

```
Auth::user()
```

both the same and get authenticate user details from database

Comment: so it's better to use session ??

Comment: i know that the two ways work but i want to use the most performance way

Comment: yeah  ,i think this the only method to get auth data for jwt and session just if you have multiple auth user you should pass current guard like this: auth('your-guard-name')

Comment: The authenticated user is retreived from the session not the database (unless you're using database driver for the session) but still that would be from the sessions table not the users table

Comment: so why when update full_name  of  authenticated user then use auth()->user()->full_name we get the new updated full name @CaddyDZ?

Comment: Because the session's content is updated upon any eloquent operations on the logged in user, think about it logically, how can Laravel tell who the authenticated user is without using the session?

Comment: When using the api guard for instance, session is not used but you're forced to send the user's token or Bearer key on every request

Answer (score 1):

The `auth()` helper function or the facade for that matter is already using the session as a driver for the web guard by default...
`config/auth.php`

```php
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session', // <-- Here
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
]
```

So what you're really asking is if the session or the session is better...

Answer (score 0):

You can use auth helper for that and it's optimal enough cause its in global bootstraped $app variable witch loads in the beginning of laravel kernel loading.

Also its a good way to load other everytime-needed attributes from user in the auth() helper like auth()->id.

You can use marco to add such data to auth helper this way:

Add this to AppServiceProvider boot method or any custom provider you have to add extra field to auth helper through SessionGuard which is macroable:

```
SessionGuard::macro('mobile', function () {
        return auth()->check() ? auth()->user()->mobile : null;
});
```

Now everywhere you need simply use

```
auth()->mobile();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this marco method will help me more in my projects